# reverse and remove last value an array using array_pop / array_reverse

Tags: php, arrays

I need to first reverse an array in PHP and then remove the last value.  I tried this and it did not give me the desired result:

```
<?php if(count($this->methods)==2) array_pop(array_reverse($this->methods)); ?>
```

Or if simpler, how do I simply remove the first value of an array? I had previously tried `array_shift` but that shifts the array not removing a value.

Comment: *if(count($this->methods)==2)* there are 2 items in your array. Take that you need `$this->methods[0] `or `$this->methods[1]`

Comment: so basically I am trying to use the logic of if there are two methods available, only use method #2. hope that helps

Comment: In that case, why don't you just use the return value of array_pop?

Comment: So you gave up and none of these helped you?

Answer (score 0):

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) uses a reference (note the **&$array**).  Therefore you need to use a variable to store the reversed array before passing it to array_pop.

---

Based on your comments, you can use the return value of array_pop if you're trying to get the value of the last element without needing to reverse the array.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first value of an array use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
if(count($this->methods)==2) array_shift($this->methods));
```

If you want to store it:

```
$first = array_shift($this->methods);
```